# Null fields in JSON Array java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to access JSON file on the internet and it has some null fields like this one:

```
{
    "c":[ 
        {
            "v": "Week 10"
        }, 
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        {
            "v": null
        }]
}
```

when I try to access them to put them on a string an exception is thrown 
I've used `JSONObject.isNull(""), JSONObject.toString().equals("null")` and non of them work help please!!

Answer (score 0):

you can read this Json use getJsonArray to get a List, and then loop this list.

```
String jstr = "{'c':[{'v': 'Week 10'}, null,null,null,null,{'v': null}]}";
JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(jstr);
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("c");
for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.size();i++){
    System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
}
```

or you can read this json into a bean, below is the sample code,hope this can help you.

c.java

```
public class c {

private String v;

public String getV() {
    return v;
}

public void setV(String v) {
    this.v = v;
}
```

}

json2Bean.java

```
public class json2Bean {

private List<c> c;

public List<c> getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(List<c> c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```

}

json2String.java

```
public class json2String {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jstr = "{'c':[{'v': 'Week 10'}, null,null,null,null,{'v': null}]}";

    Map<String, Class<?>> m = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    m.put("c", c.class);

    json2Bean myBean = (json2Bean) JSONObject.toBean(JSONObject.fromObject(jstr), json2Bean.class, m);

    for (c e : myBean.getC()) {
        if (e != null) {
            System.out.println(e.getV());
        }
    }
}
```

}